# Django localization, extracting strings to separate message file

Tags: python, django, internationalization

Is there any simple way to extract strings from template files into a separate message files and later reference them by key in template html?

In Java Iuse properties files for strings:

```
i18n.header.title=This is title
i18n.header.content=Long content with some parameters {0} here.
```

And in jsp I use:

```
<h4><fmt:message key="18n.header.title"/></h4>
<p><fmt:message key="18n.header.title">
        <fmt:param>A param</fmt:param>
    </fmt:message>
</p>
```

Its a convenient way and i'm looking for similar ways in django.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're looking for is Django's support for [translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/) and [message files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#message-files).

In particular I think you're looking for the [blocktrans](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag) template tag.